# Issues with derivative

Tags: derivatives, differential, differential-operators

I'm a beginner at Calculus. So, don't laugh at my question. We know that $$\dfrac{d}{dx} (x^2) = 2x.$$ If $x=4$, then the value of the function $y=x^2$ becomes $16$. So shouldn't the slope be $$\dfrac{(16-0)}{(4-0)}=4\ ?$$ But $2x=8$ [assuming $x=4$].

Comment: please use Tex code. Not able to read the question.

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Mathematical_expressions

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Integrals,_sums_and_limits

Comment: The line passing by the point $(4,16)$ with slope $4$ is a secant which meets the curve $y=x^2$ at $(4,16)$ and $(0,0)$, it isn´t the tangent line.

Comment: Also relevant: the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And why the gun?

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Fractions_and_Binomials#!#Introduction

Comment: I hope my links will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you’ve used two points the calculate slope—one of which is the origin. This leads to an inaccurate conclusion about the derivative.

[image]

You can think of this as anchoring the tangent line to *two* points. For the best tangent line, you want it anchored to only *one* point via the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

You're using $\frac{16-0}{4-0}$ to calculate the gradient of the line, however this is only valid if it were a straight line from $x=0$ to $x=4$. As the line $y=x^2$ is curved, the $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ needs to be infinitesimally small, and hence we use $\frac{dy}{dx}$.